# n-th primitive root of unity

Tags: roots-of-unity

Let $p>3$.
Suppose $f$ is third primitive root of unity in $F_p$. I need to prove the following:
$(2f+1)^2=(-3)$ .

So, what I did:
$f^3=1$ but it doesn't hold for first and second power of $f$.
Then, $(2f+1)^2 = 4(f^2 + f + 1) - 3$

But then, if I multiply the LHS by $f$, I will get $f^3 + f^2 + f = 1 + f^2 + f$ .
So, $f$ must be $1$. I am clearly confusing something here. I am doing this too straightforward?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Well, for one thing, $(2f+1)^2\neq 4(f^2+f+1)$.

Comment: Multiply the LHS of _what_ by $f$?

Comment: Well, from $f^3 + f^2 + f = 1 + f^2 + f$, you don't get $f=1$, but $f^3=1$, and that's not really news for a third root of $1$.

Comment: Well, since $f^3=1$ , it follows that $f^2 + f + 1 = 0 ( mod (p))$ . Then, $(2f+1)^2=4f^2 + 4f + 1= 4(f^2 + f + 1 ) - 3 = -3$ . Was, pretty simple I think, Thanks for comments.

Comment: You should assume that $f\ne 1$ or $p>3$ and $3|(p-1),$ otherwise $1$ is the only $3$-th root of unity and then obviously $f^2+f+1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod p$